# Linked content files not included in TFS build output

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I've got a solution with the following structure:

- Foo.Service (Windows service project)
- Foo.IntegrationTests (MSTest project referencing Foo)
- Foo.Domain (class libraries)

Foo.Service has **linked files** which are configured like so:

- **Build action: Content**
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer

When building locally, the files are copied to the output folder, as expected.

The **TFS (in the cloud) build** however, **does not include the files in** the **output folder**.
As a result the integration tests fail.

I looked around and **tried** adding **the following** to the Foo.Service project file, **without result**.

```
<Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" 
      DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)\%(Content.Link)" 
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
      Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
</Target>
```

**How** can I make sure that the **(linked) content files** are **copied to** the **output directpory in a TFS build**?

Comment: Can you replace the "OutputPath" with "OutDir" and see if that fixes your issue?

Comment: Did not fix the issue :(

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which build template you are using. If you are using GitTemplate,
please set the "Output location" property to "As Configured".

Comment: The Default Template (DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml) is used

Comment: Ok, for DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml it is the "Solution Specific Build Outputs" argument. It is set to False by default, if you set it to true, the solution outputs would be put on individual folders rather than one particular folder.